# Getting error when varchar value used in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named 'TABLE_RELATION'. I want to use some of relation codes to filter values from a select query. But when I am trying using IN operator getting an error ***Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ''301','302','303','304','305','306','312'' to data type smallint.***

RELATION_CODE column is type smallint.

```
declare @guar_tab varchar(max)
declare @guar_tab_VALUES varchar(max)
select @guar_tab=COALESCE(''+@guar_tab+''',''','''')+convert(varchar(100), RELATION_CODE) from TABLE_RELATION where RELATION_CODE>300 and RELATION_CODE<400
SET @guar_tab_VALUES=(select @guar_tab)+''''+''
SELECT @guar_tab_VALUES
select * from TABLE_RELATION where  RELATION_CODE in ( @guar_tab_VALUES)
```

When I tried '301','302','303','304','305','306','312' instead of @guar_tab_VALUES, it is working fine.

How can I solve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual goal is here, but you can't use a **scalar** value/variable as a replacement for a list. What you have is the same as `WHERE RELATION_CODE IN ('''301'',''302'',''303'',''304'',''305'',''306'',''312''')` That's just one long string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a list of values like this.  You are passing in a string with a single value that happens to have a bunch of commas.

One simplish method for your code is to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
select *
from TABLE_RELATION
where RELATION_CODE in (@guar_tab_VALUES);
';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@guar_tab_VALUEs', @guar_tab_VALUEs);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query, but I feel I'm missing something. What's wrong with just:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_RELATION
WHERE RELATION_CODE > 300 AND RELATION_CODE < 400;
```

You're creating a delimited list of values from the table `TABLE_RELATION`, and then returning all those rows. There's literally no point. Based on what we have there's no need for dynamic SQL, or an `IN`.

We *could* express what you've written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_RELATION TR
WHERE TR.RELATION_CODE IN (SELECT sq.RELATION_CODE
                           FROM TABLE_RELATION sq
                           WHERE sq.RELATION_CODE > 300
                             AND sq.RELATION_CODE < 400);
--or
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_RELATION TR
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TABLE_RELATION sq
              WHERE sq.RELATION_CODE > 300
                AND sq.RELATION_CODE < 400
                AND TR.RELATION_CODE = sq.RELATION_CODE);
```

As you can see, there's no need for the subquery,just put it in the main `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's list of numbers.
So something like this

```
select * from table1 
where col1 in ('1', '2', '3')
```

can be written as

```
select * from table1 
where col1 IN (1, 2, 3)
```

But `IN` accepts  a list of values, or a query that returns a list of values.
So just adding 1 string with values just won't do.
F.e. this won't work if col1 is a number.

```
select * from table1 where col1 IN ('1,2,3')
```

Because the string '1,2,3' can't be implicitly converted to a number.

Using a query could work

```
select * from table1 
where col1 IN (select n from nums where n between 1 and 9)
```

If you do want use a variable that contains a list of numbers?
Then using a table variable might be for you.

```
DECLARE @NumTbl TABLE (n smallint primary key);

INSERT INTO @NumTbl (n) 
SELECT DISTINCT RELATION_CODE
FROM TABLE_RELATION 
WHERE RELATION_CODE > 300
  AND RELATION_CODE < 400;

declare @guar_tab_values varchar(max);

select @guar_tab_values = concat(@guar_tab_values+', ', n) from @NumTbl order by n;

select @guar_tab_values as guar_tab_values;

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_RELATION 
WHERE RELATION_CODE IN (select n from @NumTbl);
```

In your case I would just use those criteria in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_RELATION 
WHERE RELATION_CODE > 300
  AND RELATION_CODE < 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Such requirement comes many times in many different scenarios. so why not create generic solution.

We can a create user define function to slit comma separated string and return data in form of table.

Generic User Define Function :

```
-- FUNCTION TO SPLIT STRINGS.
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
@returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @pos INT

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
END

INSERT INTO @returnList
SELECT @stringToSplit

RETURN
END
```

Call use define function:

```
declare @guar_tab varchar(max)
declare @guar_tab_VALUES varchar(max)
select @guar_tab=COALESCE(''+@guar_tab+',','')+convert(varchar(100), RELATION_CODE) from TABLE_RELATION where RELATION_CODE>300 and RELATION_CODE<400
select * from TABLE_RELATION where  RELATION_CODE in (SELECT[Name] FROM dbo.SplitString( @guar_tab))
```

I hope this will help you :)